# What is the [fact] attribute?

Tags: c#

I'm sure this is super simple, but I'm clearly not Googling the right thing.  In several unit test related blogs, I've seen the attribute [fact] given to several methods, but I can't seem to figure out what this means.  Example:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [Fact]
    public void Foo()
    {

    }

    [Fact]
    public void Bar()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the namespace for [Fact] ? I've installed XUnit, but VS can not find [Fact] attribute.

Comment: Fact... jeez, why not just call it TestAttribute? If people need to google it, you know you have made a poor naming choice :\

Comment: In the GitHub doc for xUnit it explains the Fact attribute and how to use it in a example "Facts are tests which are always true. They test invariant conditions." https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html

Comment: this question is the defacto answer on google, should have more upvote.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

It belongs to the [xUnit](https://xunit.net/docs/comparisons) unit testing framework.

It says that the method is a unit test.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed it was part of the Visual Studio unit test framework, hence why I didn't get any meaningful results.

Comment: What's the difference between **Fact** and **Test**?

Comment: The [Fact] attribute is used by xUnit Test Framework. The [Test] attribute is used by another test framework. Both mark the procedure as a test.

Comment: Do they mark it as a "test" in general, or a "unit test" specifically? This isn't clear from the 14+ upvoted comment that says "Both mark the procedure as a test".

Comment: This is a useful comparison of the test framework attributes https://xunit.net/docs/comparisons